# Gradient glowing button using html and css

Tags: html, css

I've tried the codes for creating a glowing button on my webpage, but It's been done, below are some code which I tried.

```css
     .button {
      background-color: #1c87c9;
      -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
      border-radius: 60px;
      border: none;
      color: #eeeeee;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 5px 15px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
<button class=""> Hello World! </button
```

> Please do help me to create this glowing button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want gradient glowing button you should use:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(firstcolor, secondcolor);
```

you could also add:

```
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px yellow; (or any color that you want)
```

Answer (score 1):

change `<button class=""> Hello World! </button`

to `<button class="button"> Hello World! </button>`

The css .button selector is looking for the class="button". The `.` denotes class. [Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I've tried putting the button class name but still not been fixed, I think there would be any issue in css file

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkbra5sj/). Make sure your css file is linked between the `<head>...</head>` tags, link the css file with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="FileName.css">`

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you're targeting a class name of "button", but your button has no class name! Try assigning the button a class name and then use that name in the CSS, like so:

```css
.myButton {
  background-color: #1c87c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="myButton"> Hello World! </button
```

Answer (score 0):

class value of the button is missing, also css must be in
`<style> .button{...} </style>`

```css
.button {
  background-color: #1c87c9;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="button"> Hello World! </button>
```

Comment: The SO snippet system has dealt with the insertion of the style tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use `button` instead of `.button`.

```css
button {
    background-color: #1c87c9;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    border: none;
    color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello World</button>
```